# Sweat [Countable / Uncountable]

Tags: word-usage, indefinite-article, uncountable-nouns

I was wondering if the indefinite article "a" is necessary in the following sentences, whereas the noun "[sweat](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sweat)" in an uncountable word.

> 1. I broke out in **a** cold sweat from pain.

> 2. I broke out in **a** sweat from embarrassment.

Please kindly clarify the reason why this article is used along with the noun "sweat".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sweat" is both a noun (for the liquid excretion) and a verb (*to sweat*). However, this is an additional noun usage - "*a* sweat" is an idiomatic way to describe a *bout of sweating*, just like you would say someone has *a fever*. Both your examples are this noun usage.

"Sweat" as a liquid is like all other liquids - uncountable in itself, but you can count smaller quantities of it. Droplets of sweat are usually referred to as "beads of sweat". So, just as you could say "*a* glass of water", you could say "*a* bead of sweat".